# How can i fix overlaping elements in PDF generated using iText7 and canvas

Tags: c#, pdf, canvas, itext, overlap

Here we can see my Service that i use to generate PDF:

```
public class PdfGeneratorService : IPdfGeneratorService
    {
        public byte[] GeneratePdfFromSvgFile(IFormFile svgFile, string colorMode)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(svgFile.OpenReadStream()))
            {
                string svgContent = reader.ReadToEnd();

                XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDocument.Load(svgFile.OpenReadStream());

                if (xmlDocument.DocumentElement != null && xmlDocument.DocumentElement.Name == "svg")
                {
                    using (MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(
                            new PdfWriter(pdfStream,
                            new WriterProperties().SetCompressionLevel(0)));

                        PageSize pageSize = PageSize.A4.Rotate();
                        doc.SetDefaultPageSize(pageSize);

                        XmlDocument modifiedXmlDocument = SvgColorTransformer.ApplyColorTransformation(xmlDocument, colorMode);
                        string modifiedSvgContent = modifiedXmlDocument.OuterXml;

                        foreach (string pageSvgContent in GeneratePages.GenerateSvgPages(modifiedSvgContent))
                        {
                            doc.AddNewPage();

                            PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(doc.GetLastPage());

                            // Scale transformation
                            float scaleX = .704f; // Adjust as needed
                            float scaleY = .704f; // Adjust as needed

                            Rectangle pageRectangle = doc.GetLastPage().GetPageSize();
                            float svgWidth = pageRectangle.GetWidth() * scaleX;
                            float svgHeight = pageRectangle.GetHeight() * scaleY;
                            float translateX = (pageRectangle.GetWidth() - svgWidth) / 99;
                            float translateY = (pageRectangle.GetHeight() - svgHeight) / 90;

                            // Apply the scaling transformation to the canvas
                            canvas.ConcatMatrix(scaleX, 0, 0, scaleY, translateX, translateY);

                            string adjustedSvgContent = AdjustSvg.AdjustSvgContent(pageSvgContent, translateX, translateY, scaleX, scaleY);

                            // Draw the scaled SVG content on the canvas
                            SvgConverter.DrawOnDocument(adjustedSvgContent, doc, 1);
                        }

                        doc.Close();

                        return pdfStream.ToArray();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new BadRequestException("Invalid SVG format");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

SVG before export to PDF

[image: SVG before export to PDF]

SVG after export to PDF

[image: SVG after export to PDF]

Now i have to enable text-anchor: end;
I found in iText7 documentation ther is dedicated option for that:

[image: Text-anchor from documentation]

But i dont know how can i use it in my code.

Comment: @KJ Im using 1920x1080 on my 15,6 inch laptop, which is 141 DPI. Can you explain why you think i have to many translate to follow? Maybe you have an idea what can i change in my code to fix my problem? And how can i check my translation is 50% or centered? Cheers!

Comment: What do you propose to do to simplify it? @KJ

Comment: Sorry but, im a C# Intern for now and ive never used fiddle and i dont know how to use it at this moment. Maybe i can use debbugger to check if my method works fine or not?

Comment: Which result u wanna see?

Comment: Ok soo i generated a pdf from a SVG and it looks like this: https://docdro.id/9zNkTw5
I removed all element and I just left element which is overlaping. Soo, as you can see "Number of pages" is moved right and its overlaping on "304" which possition also changed a little bit to the right. On the original SVG file all possitions are good. @KJ

Comment: Soo I can simply delete these two methods: AdjustTextTranslation and AdjustSvgContent and try different way? Maybe you can give me some tips how should i start working with it? :) @KJ

Comment: Ok, but the question is why only few elements changed their location. Its rly hard to understand for me, and still i dont know how to start fixing it in code :( @KJ

Comment: Yea of course i can easly change possitioning like that. But the thing is thath have to be automaticly changed by my controller :) This is not only one element, there is few elements which is changing their location in generated PDF. Im asking how can i do this in my code that i put above (PdfGeneratorService and other two helpers methods) to automaticly find wrong positioned elements and apply some changes to move them into right possition.